# Can I repeatedly switch between blocking and non-blocking behavior?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, blocking, nonblocking

I have two processes who are communicating via Unix domain sockets in a primary/replica setup. The replica needs to periodically ask the primary for guidance, but it should only do so if the primary indicates its ready to offer said guidance. If the primary is ready, the replica should query the primary and wait for a response; otherwise, it should continue with its current task.

Normally, I'd use a POSIX semaphore to communicate to the replica whether or not the primary is ready -- it's fast and lightweight. Unfortunately, I happen to be working on a research system that doesn't support POSIX shared memory. Hence, Unix sockets are all I have.

I know that non-blocking reads are quite fast, so I'm wondering if I could do something like this:

- Open a connection between the replica and the primary.
- Set the replica's end to non-blocking.
- Periodically check if the replica can read from the primary.
- If the read succeeds, **switch the socket to blocking and query the primary**. Once the query is complete, **return the socket to non-blocking**.
- If the read fails, continue until the next check.

Can I repeatedly switch a socket between blocking and non-blocking behavior?

Comment: Since it is a socket, why not simply use [`recv(descriptor, buffer, length, MSG_DONTWAIT)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) for the nonblocking reads, and `recv(descriptor, buffer, length, 0)` for the blocking reads? Similarly for [`send(descriptor, buffer, length, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_NOSIGNAL)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) for nonblocking and `send(descriptor, buffer, length, MSG_NOSIGNAL)` for blocking writes?

Comment: Usually, this kind of problems is managed with `select`. Read the documentation of `select` and you will be able to find out a clean architecture for your program.

Comment: @Marian: ah, just flip between no timeout and an infinite timeout. I've been using select/epoll in other parts of the primary, why didn't I think of that? Please consider submitting that as an answer. Thank you!!

Comment: @NominalAnimal: That's also a fantastic suggestion -- I didn't know about the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag.

Answer (score 2):

[You can](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577384-setting-a-file-descriptor-to-blocking-or-non-block/) using fcntl:

```
int file_descriptor;
int flags;

// open file_descriptor

flags = fcntl(file_descriptor, F_GETFL, 0);
flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;           // set blocking
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;            // set non-blocking
fcntl(file_descriptor, F_SETFL, flags);
```

But I think you program will be more simple if you just use two sockets. Use one for control (non-blocking) and one for data (blocking). Use the control socket to pass "ready"/"not ready" messages, and the data socket for your "guidance".

This eliminates the need to open/close sockets or modify their configuration repeatedly and should simplify the control flows in your program. It also separates data and control flows in your programs, which is generally good practice.

Comment: I'd planned to leave the socket open and reuse it throughout the replica's lifespan, but the two socket idea is definitely intriguing. Hadn't thought about separating data/control -- makes a lot of sense!

Comment: With regard to your edit: could I flip-flop back and forth repeatedly? I'm warming to the two socket idea a lot though, so it's more out of curiosity than anything else.

Comment: @tonysdg I don't see any reason it *couldn't* work, but I find socket communication to be challenging sometimes. I don't trust myself to always anticipate potential deadlock, so I prefer to simplify control flows and avoid blocking reads wherever possible. I haven't personally tried to change the blocking/non-blocking mode of sockets after opening.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a separate thread with a permanently blocking socket. Have the primary send something when it's ready to be queried. Thread blocks trying to receive that: when it does, it issues the query etc., and then goes back to the initial receive.

**EDIT** It's not a good idea to switch a fundamentally non-blocking system into blocking mode, even temporarily, and even with a read timeout, as the system will certainly stop for at least the timeout period some time, depending on the behaviour of the peer and the intervening network. You're far better off isolating that dependency to a separate thread.

Comment: I'd considered this approach but am hesitant to introduce multi-threading to my replica (again, due to the research nature of the system). I'll rethink my opposition, but I'd also like to know (out of curiosity) if the behavior I described is allowed/correct/works. Do you have any insight into that?

Comment: It's not a good idea to switch a fundamentally non-blocking system into blocking mode, even temporarily, and even with a read timeout, as the system will certainly stop for at least the timeout period some time, depending on the behaviour of the peer and the intervening network. You're far better off isolating that dependency to a separate thread. I don't think 'research' is sufficient motivation for avoiding a threading model.

Comment: It is when the "research" part of the system is the OS, which only has limited support of multi-threading :-) I don't want to dive into those details, but suffice it to say it's an academic research project that has me hamstrung in a variety of ways. I'll nevertheless skip the non-blocking/blocking switch and test the separate thread and see if it's supported -- thank you for the insight!

Comment: Alternatively use `select()` if it's available and leave it all non-blocking. Don't switch.